# Holding greater or equal relation between two terms

Tags: coq

```
H:count k (match d with
|nil=>nil
|s::l=>(s::firstn n l))
end <=
count 0 (match d with
|nil=>nil
|s::l=>(s::firstn n l))
end
```

Where n is natural number and d is list nat. From above H may i extract information that (s::firstn n l) contains more zeros than k.

Comment: I'm confused. Seems like you didn't copy and paste the entire hypothesis? The parentheses don't match in pairs. So I can't really be sure about what you're trying to do here...

Comment: Please note that `H` is an hypothesis about `k`, `d` and `n` only.  `s` and `l` are just local variables in `H` statement.

Comment: From s and l used (locally) in H ,what maximum information i can extract ? Especially when d is non empty . Secondly, i want to perform induction on list (firstn n l) so that list become (s::b0::firstn n l). then i  write count k (s::b0::firstn n l) <= count 0 (s::b0::firstn n l) from H.

Comment: @nihakee Welcome to SO! We would like to help, but we cannot understand your question without more details. Please make your question clearer so that we can help you.